# Switch to llvm-13 as default (instead of llvm-10) in Ubuntu 20.04. How?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clang, llvm

I have installed both `llvm-10.0.0` and `llvm-13.0.0` on an `Ubuntu 20.04` machine. Typing e.g. `clang --version` or `clangd --version` always returns the `10.0.0` versions.
I want to use the `13.0.0` version as defualt.
How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives)  to change the default version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install \
        /usr/bin/llvm-config       llvm-config      /usr/bin/llvm-config-13.0.0  200 
......
```

Total example is [here](https://gist.github.com/jc00ke/b55cf7d16d584fbb2b92).